# unable to apply formula to dataframe first column value using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

[image][image]i have this dataframe and for the column A i want a formula to be applied as below
for example consider the first value under colum A as 2492248593

value*8/1000000000 and the output should be in the dataframe. how do i achieve it.**

Steps i tried as below:

```
maxthroughput=df.iloc[:,0] 
Max_Thput=maxthroughput*8/1000000000 
print("Max_Thput",Max_Thput) 
roundUp = Max_Thput.apply(np.ceil) 
print (roundUp)
```

But the above my logic ll create another dataframe which is of series type.. is it possible to use the main df and calculate the formula and get the output results updated in the same DF?

Comment: Steps i tried as below                                                                       
maxthroughput=df.iloc[:,0]
Max_Thput=maxthroughput*8/1000000000
print("Max_Thput",Max_Thput)
roundUp = Max_Thput.apply(np.ceil)
print (roundUp)

Comment: But the above my logic ll create another dataframe which is of series type.. is it possible to use the main df and calculate the formula and get the output results updated in the same DF?

Comment: Just use `df['new'] = df['A'] *8/1000000000`  ?

Comment: Sean it works abosolutely fine.. but its long number and am trying to round the numbers as below df['new'] = round(df[A] *8/1000000000)
but getting an error as below      File "/phaedrus/home/K/Mya/env2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 112, in wrapper
    "{0}".format(str(converter)))

Comment: You can try:  `(df['A'] *8/1000000000).round().astype(int)`

Comment: Excellent.. it works fine. i was trying in other way that didn worked..

Comment: That's great it works for you.   BTW, please consider also to upvote the answer.

Comment: Remember that normally you cannot directly apply Python functions to a Pandas series.  You have to find corresponding Pandas function (e.g. the Pandas round() function here) or use .map() or .apply() to apply other non-Pandas functions on the Pandas objects.

Comment: i  think i did upvote also. pls check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to round to 0 decimal point and cast to integer (if necessary)

```
df['new'] = (df['A'] *8/1000000000).round().astype(int)
```

or if you want to get the ceiling of values (without casting to integer):

```
df['new'] = (df['A'] *8/1000000000).map(np.ceil)
```